# .NET Framework 4.6.2 and .NET Standard 2.0 incompatibility

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

A project targets **.NET Framework 4.6.2**.

A project uses NuGet package Entity Framework Core that references **.NET Standard 2.0** (it appeared in **packages** folder)

As far as I know, **.NET 4.6.2** and **.NET Standard 2.0** are incompatible.
Could it cause any issues?

Comment: As far as I know they are *not* incompatible.  .NETStandard 2.0 requires 4.6.1, they did not break it in 4.7.  Make this a real question by describing what goes wrong.

Comment: My mistake. I mean .NET 4.6.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of the latest tooling updates in VS 2017 15.3 and .NET Core 2.0.0 SDK (released in August 2017), the minimum version of .NET Framework that supports .NET Standard 2.0 is 4.6.1.

This is achieved by the tooling which adds compatibility DLLs to make sure that libraries load and work. There are only a handful of APIs that aren't supported on 4.6.1-4.7, but Entity Framework Core is supposed to work on 4.6.1+.

For .NET Framework 4.7.1+, the tooling no longer needs to inject those libraries.

Comment: `There are only a handful of APIs that aren't supported on 4.6.1`  <- could you provide a ref of those?

Comment: Without a reference to elaborate the "handful of APIs", this answer isn't as useful as it can be.